# require help regarding google map embadding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want my web's register users to store their location (latitude & longitude) from provided gmap in their profile page, i hv embeded google map successfully, but dont know how to get latitude & longitude of current location of gmap set by user.....
optional *current zoom value
please help

Comment: If the lat/long is set by the user, why don't you have the information? Why not capture it when they set it?

Comment: it is not set user just drags gmap moves his home to center of map, and clicks "set my location" button,... now its my task to get lat/lag from that gmap location and store in db.... i dont know which functions appy on gmap to get current lat/lang

Comment: **I got here what I was looking for, in this link**
http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/01/22/get-latitude-and-longitude-with-google-maps-v3/            
a **google map embeding** which is able to return **current lat/lan, zoom level** and **marker at center**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Assuming your map is stored in a variable called `map`, this is how to get the center of the map (returns a LatLng):

```
map.getCenter()
```

> Returns the position displayed at the center of the map. Note that
>   this LatLng object is not wrapped. See LatLng for more information.

And the zoom level of the map (returns a number):

```
map.getZoom()
```

Comment: **I got here what I was looking for, in this link**
http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/01/22/get-latitude-and-longitude-with-google-maps-v3/            
a **google map embeding** which is able to return **current lat/lan, zoom level** and **marker at center**

Comment: @FakhrAlam, um... that link just says to do it *exactly as my answer explains*....

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a click handler to the map and get the clicked coordinates:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(ev){
  console.log('Click at: ' + ev.latLng.Ua + ', ' + ev.latLng.Va + '. Zoom: ' + map.getZoom());
});
```

You can see an example in action here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9pQQ/17/)

Comment: i have pasted this code .......... ........... ......... ......... .............. .......... ...... <br>\n <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=new+york&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=39.371738,86.572266&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=New+York&amp;t=f&amp;z=13&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>..........text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>

Comment: @FakhrAlam I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're trying to say

Comment: **I got here what I was looking for, in this link**
http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2010/01/22/get-latitude-and-longitude-with-google-maps-v3/            
a **google map embeding** which is able to return **current lat/lan, zoom level** and **marker at center**